# How to combine arrays in php?

Tags: php, arrays, multidimensional-array

I have these arrays:

$array1

```
Array
            (
                [0] => Array
                    (
                        [state] => AE
                        [state_pri] => 0
                    )

                [1] => Array
                    (
                        [state] => AK
                        [state_pri] => 0
                    )

                [2] => Array
                    (
                        [state] => AL
                        [state_pri] => 0
                    )
)
```

$array2

```
Array
            (
                [0] => Array
                    (
                        [0] => Array
                            (
                                [count1] => 0
                            )

                    )

                [1] => Array
                    (
                        [0] => Array
                            (
                                [count1] => 1
                            )

                    )

                [2] => Array
                    (
                        [0] => Array
                            (
                                [count1] => 18
                            )

                    )
)
```

$array3

```
Array
            (
                [0] => Array
                    (
                        [0] => Array
                            (
                                [count] => 0
                            )

                    )

                [1] => Array
                    (
                        [0] => Array
                            (
                                [count] => 1
                            )

                    )

                [2] => Array
                    (
                        [0] => Array
                            (
                                [count] => 18
                            )

                    )
)
```

...and I would like to get something like this:

```
Array
            (
                [0] => Array
                    (
                        [state] => AE
                        [state_pri] => 0
                        [0] => Array
                            (
                                [count] => 0
                            )
                        [0] => Array
                            (
                                [count1] => 0
                            )
                    )

                [1] => Array
                    (
                        [state] => AK
                        [state_pri] => 0
                        [1] => Array
                            (
                                [count] => 0
                            )
                        [1] => Array
                            (
                                [count1] => 0
                            )
                    )

                [2] => Array
                    (
                        [state] => AL
                        [state_pri] => 0
                        [2] => Array
                            (
                                [count] => 0
                            )
                        [2] => Array
                            (
                                [count1] => 0
                            )
                    )
)
```

Any ideas on how to do this?

*Edit:* Just to add some more code, if I use `array_merge` I get:

```
Array
            (
                [0] => Array
                    (
                        [state] => AE
                        [state_pri] => 0
                    )

                [1] => Array
                    (
                        [state] => AK
                        [state_pri] => 0
                    )

                [2] => Array
                    (
                        [state] => AL
                        [state_pri] => 0
                    )
                [3] => Array
                    (
                        [0] => Array
                            (
                                [count] => 0
                            )

                    )

                [4] => Array
                    (
                        [0] => Array
                            (
                                [count] => 1
                            )

                    )

                [5] => Array
                    (
                        [0] => Array
                            (
                                [count] => 18
                            )

                    )
                 .....
)
```

Comment: [`array_merge()`](http://us3.php.net/manual/en/function.array-merge.php)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you're looking for is still a bit difficult to make out. Let me know if this achieves the desired results:

```
foreach ($array1 as $key => $val) {
  $array1[$key][] = $array3[$key];
  $array1[$key][] = $array2[$key];
}

print_r($array1);
```

Comment: it worked. Thanks for the logic. i tried something similar but i see not where i fail. Thanks all.

Answer (score 0):

What about the array_merge function?

http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.array-merge.php

Comment: it merges them one one after each other `array1->array2->array3` and not all inside one

Comment: @Patrioticcow perhaps you could post code specifically demonstrating (in a simplified way) how you'd like the behavior to differ from `array_merge()`? It's not easy to see with all those arrays `print_r`'d

Comment: i edited my post. `array_merge` is not combining the arrays just add them one after eachother

Answer (score 0):

```
$merged = array();
foreach (array($array1,$array2,$array3) as $array) {
    foreach ($array as $key=>$value) {
        if (!isset($merged[$key])) {
            $merged[$key] = array();    
        }
        $merged[$key] += $value; 
    }
}
print_r($merged);
```

Comment: The way you are asking it right now, it's impossible. An array can't have multiple entries with identical keys.

Answer (score 0):

```
$combined=$array0 + $array1;
```

Try that one